# derivative of the expectation of max function

Tags: probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

What is the first and second and third derivative with respect to $w_{i}$ of the following function ?? ($r_{i}$'s are  random variables)
$$f(w,r)=E\bigg[\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{w_{i}(a-r_{i})},0\bigg)_{+}^3 \bigg]$$

I am getting the answer: $\frac{\partial f}{\partial w_{i}}=3E\bigg[\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{w_{i}(a-r_{i})},0\bigg)^2_{+} (a-r_{i})\bigg]$

and  $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial w_{i}^2}=6E\bigg[\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n}{w_{i}(a-r_{i})},0\bigg)_{+} (a-r_{i})^2\bigg].$

Also what would be the third derivative ?

I am not sure about the answers. please clarify me.

Comment: What is $(x,0)_+$? Would you be mixing the two notations $x_+$ and $\max(x,0)$ for the positive part of $x$?

Comment: yes...max$(x,0)$ is same as $(x,0)_{+}$

Comment: The convention is to use capital letters for your random variables

Comment: Actually in finance $r_{i}$ indicates return random variable of asset $i$

Comment: Sorry but the notation $(x,0)_+$ does not exist, please replace it by $x_+$ or by $\max(x,0)$.